# Nativescript + Angular: Unable to start cleanup process error when running 'tns run android'

Tags: android, macos, angular2-nativescript

I am building a project in Nativescript + Angular on macOS Big Sur.  I am unable to run or build the android version of the project. I keep getting this error:

```
Error while reporting exception: Error: Unable to start Cleanup process.
```

Is anyone familiar with this error? I ran `tns clean` successfully as well as `tns platform remove android`, `tns platform add android`, `tns prepare android`, but if I run `tns build android` or `tns run android` I get the error above.

Here is my package.json. Let me know if there are any files that would be useful to see.

```
    {
  "name": "@nativescript/template-hello-world-ng",
  "main": "main.js",
  "version": "7.0.8",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "angular",
    "{N}",
    "template"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-chart": "^1.1.29",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "^7.3.0",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.0",
    "nativescript": "^7.2.0",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^7.0.1",
    "nativescript-custom-bottomsheet": "^1.0.6",
    "nativescript-fontawesome": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-ngx-fonticon": "^7.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "^8.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "^7.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "~7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "gitHead": "41a7254d3bc134fd3c258761f3c6e1c3d54e6d41",
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a helpful error message:

```
/Users/***/Documents/GitHub/RexChange_private/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/facebookLogo.png: Error: 'L' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
```

renaming my image resources solved the issue. I guess the error is a catch all.